# How can I make recursive 'ls' command in perl?

Tags: perl, io

I tried this in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use 5.010;
state @files;

sub marin{
if (opendir DIR, $_){
   marin $_; 
} else {
  push @files, $_; 
}   
 closedir DIR;
}
$input = opendir DIR, '/home';
marin $input;
print "@files";
```

But error occurs: 'Cant opendir('DIR', undef) : No such file or directory (line 7). Which is `if(open DIR, $_)` ... why can not I use $_ as pathfile? (and thus make it as my filehandle?) Niether if I make the `$_` at the beginning of marine function as another scalar `$_ = $dir_to_open`, it wont help. Please, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Use lexicals for handles, not barewords: `opendir my $dir, $path`

Comment: You are using `$_` but nothing is setting it. There is no reason to use it anyway. You need to use [readdir](https://perldoc.pl/functions/readdir) to read the entries of a directory handle you've opened. The entries you read will also be relative to that directory, so you have to assemble its path before you can use it. Consider the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) iterator method, or [Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule) for more complex needs.

Comment: There is also no reason for the file-scoped state variable `@files`, it can just be a my variable.

Answer (score 3):

There's a particular problem in your Perl program. You aren't using the argument that you pass to your subroutine:

```
sub marin{
    if (opendir DIR, $_){
       marin $_; 
    } else {
       push @files, $_; 
    }   
  closedir DIR;
  }
```

You meant to use the first argument to the subroutine (`$_[0]`), but you use the default topic variable, (`$_`) instead. Since there's no value in `$_`, you get the error you report.

Instead, you can say:

```
opendir DIR, $_[0]
```

But that's a bit ugly. It's really a single-element access to the array `@_`, the subroutine argument list. Rather than the ugly form, use a list assignment to give those names:

```
sub marin{
    my( $file ) = @_;
    if (opendir DIR, $file){
       marin $file; 
    } else {
       push @files, $file; 
    }   
  closedir DIR;
  }
```

The next big problem is that you are using a bareword file handle  (`DIR`) in a recursive subroutine. This is effectively a global variable, so each time you open it you close the previous one. Instead, you a lexical variable. If you use a newly-declared lexical variable or a variable whose value is undef, the `opendir` (or `open`) will put a reference to the opened file handle in the variable. Now each directory handle is private to the subroutine *call* (not the subroutine definition!). For each level, there's a new directory handle in addition to all the others you've already opened:

```
sub marin{
    my( $file ) = @_;
    if (opendir my $dh, $file){
       marin $file; 
    } else {
       push @files, $file; 
    }   
  }
```

Now that should get you closer to what you want. That's only the first issues though. Each time you call `marin`, you need to decide what it's going to return and how you'll communicate that to the level above it. So far you do work

We have an example of this task in the "Reference Tricks" chapter in [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com). It's similar to this example:

```
use v5.10;

use Data::Dumper;

my $listing = marin( '/etc' );

sub marin {
    my( $dir ) = @_;

    if( opendir my $dh, $dir ) {
        my %hash;
        while( my $file = readdir($dh) ) {
            next if $file eq '.' || $file eq '..';
            next if -l $file; # symlinks can make a loop!
            $hash{$file} = marin( "$dir/$file" )
            }
        return \%hash
        }

    return;
    }

say Dumper( $listing );
```

This produces something like this, where a undef hash value indicates a plain file and a hash reference value is a subdirectory:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'php.ini.default-previous~orig' => undef,
          'networks' => undef,
          'csh.login~orig' => undef,
          'rtadvd.conf~previous' => undef,
          'group~previous' => undef,
          'mach_init_per_user.d' => {},
          'manpaths.d' => {
                            'Wireshark' => undef,
                            'MacGPG2' => undef
                          },
          'rmtab' => undef,
          'passwd' => undef,
          'master.passwd' => undef,
          ...
```

Comment: A very important change you made without mentioning is the change from a global var to a lexical var for the directory handle. The OP code would clobber the caller's handle.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am currently reading the llama book. but will definitely read the intermediate as well. Thanks!